# How to use install Theano on Python 2.7.9 on windows 8.1 Pro ?

Tags: python, windows, installation, theano

Also, it would be great if someone can help me with installation of "nolearn" package too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you don't have the import library for libpython.  This is lack for linking with msvc on Windows and does not ordinarily come with binary division.

It is probable that you python distribution was built with something else than msvc and doesn't even have an import library to distribute in which case you would have to make one.  There are some tools on the internet about how to do that, but I'm a little misty on the details and I don't have a windows machine right now.

Well, for more details you can speak with [windows tech support](http://www.spotageek.com/services/windows-technical-support.php) experts.